# MetaPost textual does not operate with luamplib

Tags: luatex, metapost, luamplib

The code

```
picture tex_pct;
tex_pct:=btex Too baffled etex scaled 3;
 

for tkn within tex_pct:
  if textual tkn:
    show "textual";
  fi
endfor
end.
```

compiled with `mptopdf` shows 4 "textual"s but the following `lualatex` example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
% text material and glyphs contours
 
picture tex_pct;
tex_pct:=btex Too baffled etex scaled 3;
 

for tkn within tex_pct:
  if textual tkn:
    show "textual";
  fi
endfor
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

does not.
Is there a reason or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a bug, but a difference in implementation. Luamplib implements `btex ... etex;` by keeping the typeset contents at the TeX side and returning only the dimensions to MetaPost. This has great advantages: done this way, the contents of `btex ... etex;` can interact with the rest of your TeX document.

If you need access to glyph positions or glyph contours, have a look at the [minim-mp](https://ctan.org/pkg/minim-mp) metapost processor, which gives you access to those data through the `infont` and `glyph of` operators. Only the next version of minim-mp will have full LaTeX support, however (it was written for plain TeX), so you will probably have to get the current development version off gitlab to try it.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll look at `minim-mp` but it would be great to interact with the rest of the TeX document _and_ be able de access the glyph positions :)